# Difference between 'on' and 'call' in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I have a question about difference between call & on argument in d3.

As far as I understood,

**1) 'on' argument**

'selection' + 'on' is focusing an event or action.
**For example**, 
d3.select().on('click', function)

or

transition().on('end', function)

above arguments are interpreted as

> when something within on() happens, do function after the event.

**2)'call' argument**

'selection'+'call' argument is drawing things on svg using the information
specified in call argument.

**For example,**

d3.select().call(d3.axisBottom(x)) -> draw axis on the selection

or
d3.select().call(brush) -> draw brush on the selection

**HOWEVER!**
I can't interprete this argument from my understanding.

```
scatter.select(".brush").call(brush.move, null)
```

which is for eliminating the brush once it's moved.
It should be something like

```
select().on(brush.move, function(){eliminating or hide brush})
```

The code above is my pseudo code.

Can anyone correct me if I understood the call and on function wrongly?
And why do I have to call(brush.move, null) to eliminate brushes?

Full code where I came across this question is in the following link.
https://jsfiddle.net/soonk/4u6zL0dn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the API docs for [`selection.call()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_call) you will notice that

```
scatter.select(".brush").call(brush.move, null)
```

is basically equivalent to

```
brush.move(scatter.select(".brush"), null)
```

When using `.call(brush.move, null)` the actual selection `scatter.select(".brush")` is passed as the first argument to `brush.move()`. The second argument `null` of the former call gets passed as the second argument to `brush.move()`.

Looking at the specification for [`brush.move()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush#brush_move) you will find (emphasis mine):

> [#](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush#brush_move) *brush*.move(*group*, *selection*)
>
> *[…]* The *selection* must be defined as an array of numbers, or **null to clear the brush selection**.

Putting these two bits together it is easy to understand why the first statement is used to clear the brush selection.

Comment: Yeah, I understand the point but the reason I was confused is that how it works are totally different from how on and call normally work. I see it as a kinda exception. Am I seeing this correctly?

Comment: @BS100 Not really, the methods are used pretty much the same way they are *normally* used. `.on()` is used to register event handlers while `.call()` is used to do exactly what its name says: call a function. Don't let `brush.move` fool you, that's not an event, it actually is a function (https://github.com/d3/d3-brush/blob/master/src/brush.js#L218) that gets called. And because the second argument passed to it is `null` it will clear the brush selection on lines [239-253](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush/blob/master/src/brush.js#L239-L253),